# windows bock firewall powershell script not working

Tags: powershell, firewall

I use testing firewall using ps cmds; after they run successfully; but when I open browser, I am still open to visit websites; do I miss anything and how to debug this? or is it because other exiting firewall rules overwrite mine?

New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block Inbound Port 80, 443" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 80,443 -Protocol TCP -Action Block -Profile Domain, Private, Public  -Enabled :True

```
 New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block Outbound Port 80, 443" -Direction Outbound -LocalPort 80,443 -Protocol TCP -Action Block -Profile Domain, Private, Public -Enabled :True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to specify `-RemotePort` instead of `-LocalPort` for outbound traffic. Some other notes:

There's no reason to explicitly block **inbound** 80/443 traffic - the windows firewall doesn't block traffic from established sessions

**Block** rules apply before other rules with [few exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd421709(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Your rule as it is in your question should work fine after fixing the port direction, but double-check that it did actually get created, and that it's enabled:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'Block Outbound Port 80, 443'
```

Best practice is to set the firewall to block **all** outbound connections by enabling the setting "Outbound connections that do not match a rule are blocked". Then create only exception/allow rules.

Comment: If I do need to block inbound traffic if I do need it? I tried both local port and remote port; it does not working? when you established sessions, if I close and reopen browser, is it established gone or reboot the machine to break the established session?

Comment: @BLL New rules immediately apply, even to established sessions. If you do need to block specific inbound traffic, your command should look like `New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 80` vs outbound `New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -RemotePort 80`. I wrote there's no reason for you to block Inbound traffic if you want to block websites, because the `LocalPort` is chosen randomly.

Comment: @Cpt.Whate I tried New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 80 but seems it doesn't working; (I still can visit youtube video; if inbound traffic were blocked; there should be not youtbue video, am I correct? or how do I test inbound traffic is blocked?) Thanks

Comment: @BLL No, it was just an example. To block web traffic, you can would do something like `New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -RemotePort 443 -DisplayName "Block 443 out" -Protocol TCP -Action Block -Profile Any -Enabled True`. Then make sure the firewall is actually enabled with `Get-NetFirewallProfile | Select Name,Enabled`